# Can not send email after iOS 8.0.2 update

Tags: ios

After installing the iOS 8.0.2 update I am unable to send email. I can open amd receive but not respond. Here is the message I receive. Unable to deliver mail. An error occurred while divering this message. Can anyone advise me on how to correct this problem. I did not have problems until the update to 8.0.2 this afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to reset network settings.
2. If that does not work then try deleting your mail account from device, then add it back & restart device.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following suggestions:

- Check if you've access to internet (or change the network).
- Reboot the device by holding down on the Sleep and Home buttons at the same time for about 10-15 seconds until the Apple Logo appears.
- Check if you've your Mail configured in Settings correctly.
- Check your authentication details and server if it's correct.
- Check 'Use SSL' option if it's required or not for the e-mail.
- Use different app for mailing (such as GMail).

See also:

- [Get help with Mail on iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/TS3899) at Apple Support
- [Add an email account on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201320)  at Apple Support
- [iCloud: Troubleshooting iCloud Mail](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203528)  at Apple Support
- [Can’t Send Emails on iPad – Troubleshooting Steps](http://ipadhelp.com/ipad-help/ipad-cant-send-emails-troubleshooting-steps/)
- [eHow: Why does my iPad say "cannot connect to server"?](http://www.ehow.co.uk/info_8693415_ipad-say-cannot-connect-server.html)